# Отправка данных с формы в формате JSON на сервер

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

надо отправить на сервер данные введенные в контактной формы на сайте, в формате JSON (на сервере CORS запрос разрешен) при отправке получаю **Status 415**

```js
  var inpName = document.querySelector('#name');
  var inpPhone = document.querySelector('#phone');
  var inpEmail = document.querySelector('#email');
  var inpMessage = document.querySelector('#message');

 function ajax(params) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    console.log('readyState: ' + xhr.readyState + ' status: ' + xhr.status);
   }
  }

  xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/sendmail');
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.send(params);
}

var formSend = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');

formSend.addEventListener('click', function() {
 var params = "name=" + inpName.value + "&" + "phone=" + inpPhone.value + "&" + "email=" + inpEmail.value + "&" + "message=" + inpMessage.value;
 ajax(params);
});
```

Comment: При чем здесь CORS?

Comment: Для конвертации в `json` есть для этого `JSON.stringify()`.

Answer (score -2):

Посмотрите этот фрагмент [кода](https://github.com/PetersSharp/J-NOTJQUERY/blob/de6c5e2427eda07944dc5473d5c3bb1660e6a61c/J.js#L426), преобразование формы в объект, ниже есть обратная функция - объект в форму. Возможно поможет, там же есть примеры использования и пересылки объекта на сервер в Json формате.